# Insert a huge table in SQL error 1206

Tags: mysql, database

I have an issue with inserting data from one table to another, it's a MySQL database. The table that has to be imported is about 4gb big. I'm using this query to import the data.

```
insert into table1(column1, column 2)
select table2.column1, table2.column2
from table2 left join table1 on table2.column1 = table1.column1
where table1.column1 is null
```

I'm getting this error: Error Code 1206: The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size.

Increasing the buffer pool size is not an option, I don't have the rights to do this. The SQL query is working on smaller tables.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Solution:

```
 insert IGNORE into table1(column1, column 2)
 select table2.column1, table2.column2
 from table2;
```

Thank you Tom Melly for the answer.
Thank you Stefan Winkler for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a unique index on column1?

If so, you could add the ignore option to your insert, which would mean you can skip the left join:

```
insert IGNORE into table1(column1, column 2)
select table2.column1, table2.column2
from table2;
```

This will skip any inserts that would create a key-violation, but the query will still run (without the 'ignore' it would fail on the first key-violation).

Comment: Hi, there is a unique index on the column. I tried this before but somehow the data was not inserted. A part of the 2 tables is overlay, it was one big table before. Any idea what could cause the insert IGNORE to fail inserting?

Comment: "I didn't change anything" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Would splitting up the query into smaller batches (e.g. blocks of 1000) be an option?

```
insert into table1(column1, column 2)
select table2.column1, table2.column2
from table2 left join table1 on table2.column1 = table1.column1
where table1.column1 is null
limit 1000

insert into table1(column1, column 2)
select table2.column1, table2.column2
from table2 left join table1 on table2.column1 = table1.column1
where table1.column1 is null
limit 1000,1000

insert into table1(column1, column 2)
select table2.column1, table2.column2
from table2 left join table1 on table2.column1 = table1.column1
where table1.column1 is null
limit 2000,1000

-- etc.
```

Maybe you should also add an `order by` clause to the `select` in this case. Just to be sure the sort order is consistent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
This doesn't work, I tried it with numbers between 1 - 100 000 before and I keep getting the same error.

Adding an order by doesn't do it either.

Comment: mhhh ... that's bad :-( - I also thought about using LOCK TABLES/UNLOCK TABLES to lock tables explicitly. Maybe this causes a lock on the whole table instead of the single rows and thus, the amount of row locks are not necessary. But I haven't used LOCK TABLES myself yet, and so I can only guess ...

Comment: Locking the tables by using: lock tables table1 write, table2 read;
query; unlock tables; still gives me the same error. Also tried to limit the query with locked tables, same error.